# Unable to connect to mongodb atlas cluster from a kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, minikube, mongodb-cluster

Hi All I am unable to connect to mongo atlas database as a service outside the kubernetes cluster from my kubernetes cluster.

here are the steps I followed.

In my code in nodejs used dbUri= 'mongodb://username:password' + **process.env.MONGO_URL** +'/database-name'

### Here is the cluster ip service config

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
```

---

### then I have the endpoints for the same service

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo-cluster-ip-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 35.187.27.116
    ports:
    - port: 27017
  - addresses:
    - ip: 35.241.213.79
    ports:
    - port: 27017
  - addresses:
    - ip: 104.155.120.154
    ports:
    - port: 27017
```

---

### Then I have my deployment which wants to use it for the pods through an env variable

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-reg-auth-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-reg-auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-reg-auth
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ofinowregcred # this is a manually applied secret to the cluster using kubectl create secret
      containers:
      - name: user-reg-auth
        image: ofinow/user-reg-auth
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        # resources:
        #   requests:
        #     memory: "64Mi"
        #     cpu: "250m"
        #   limits:
        #     memory: "128Mi"
        #     cpu: "500m"
        env:
          - name: MONGO_URL
            value: mongo-cluster-ip-service
```

---

Now the problem is the mongo-cluster-ip-service is not getting resolved, So I am unable to connect. i kindly request for help

I followed the google best practices guide 
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information - there are so many things that could be going wrong and without any context it is impossible for anyone to answer that.

Comment: kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 35.187.27.116
    ports:
    - port: 27017
  - addresses:
    - ip: 35.241.213.79
    ports:
    - port: 27017
  - addresses:
    - ip: 104.155.120.154
    ports:
    - port: 27017

Comment: Please rather amend your question to include the relevant details - please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

It's important to ask a question that makes sense to others, try looking at what you've asked as if you're an outsider trying to get context and then you'll see little real information you've provided.

Comment: @Markoorn dont mind for the bad description. I have updated now.

Comment: @suprith did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these;

**solution A**

1. Add the endpoint of the Kubernetes cluster to the MongoDB network access IP whitelist.
2. Under the pod spec of your k8s pod (or deployment) manifest, add a **dnsPolicy** field with value set to **Default**. Hence, your Pods (your container basically) will connect to mongo through the name resolution configuration of the master node.

**solution B**

1. Add all node endpoints in your k8s cluster to the MongoDB network access IP whitelist.
2. Under the pod spec of your k8s pod (or deployment) manifest, add a **dnsPolicy** field with the value set to **ClusterFirstWithHostNet**. Since the pods run with your host network, they gain access to services listening on localhost.